# How can edge loops move independently and stay connected?

Tags: animation, edges

I have two edge loops that are moving in an animation. The edge loops are different in shape and number of vertices. The animation below shows an example of the edge loop shapes and their movement.

[image]

Using 'bridge edge loop', I can generate a geometry that blends between the two shapes, but it is not obvious how to animate it so the edge loops can be animated.

[image]

How can this geometry be animated so the edge loops can move independently and stay connected?

Comment: Which of the following have been attempted? Armatures, Proportional Edit, Shape Keys, Manual or Distance Weight Painting, Separating Loops in Edit Mode as copies.  I may not understand the question.  Perhaps others do. Perhaps another picture of your attempt would clarify.

Comment: A suggestion is to change the title of your question to something like the last sentence of your current writing .... How can this geometry be animated so the edge loops can move independently and stay connected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animate the bones of an Armature in Pose Mode.
[image]

[image]

Above is quick armature which you can greatly improve.
An armature modifier was created.
The master bone has deform disabled.  The other two bones deform the mesh.

A vertex group is selected to show weights.

Comment: Bendy bones should be worth the try in this case.